# Code First: Why Entity Framework recreates database upon every recompilation of my project even when no changes in the code are made?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

For some reason Entity Framework (Code First model) recreates my database upon every recompilation/start of my project even when I do not make any changes to the code. I wonder why? How can it be fixed?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your DbContext class look like?

Comment: Hmmm... there's too little space to quote it all but it is a standard Context class with no unusual code except for this FluentAPI piece:

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            //Set up relationship between listItems and Users tables
            modelBuilder.Entity<listItem>()
                .HasRequired(f => f.listMember)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.ListMemberId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}

Comment: It seem the problem only exists if I simultaneously start two Visual Studio projects (web app and unit tests). When I start web app only, database does not recreate.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the database strategy in Entity Framework Code First.There three default strategies

1.DropCreateDatabaseAlways

2.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists

3.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

if you need custom strategy then you can implement it using  **IDatabaseInitializer** and In your project initializer (Bootstrapper) use

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbContext>());
```